# Taking steps on local connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In topology, I saw a result about local connectedness that says: 
If $X$ is a locally connected space and $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ is a continuous **open** and surjective map then $Y$ is also locally connected. The proof is indeed straightforward, but I found on a pdf of internet that the result is also valid for **closed**, continuous and surjective maps. 
I tried to take complements and proceed identically to the argument for the one that works with open maps but I got stucked because $f[A\backslash B] \neq f[A]\backslash f[B]$. 
So, my question is:

Is the result really valid for **closed** maps?
If so, any hint to prove it is very wellcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An open continuous surjective map and a closed continuous surjective map are both special cases of a quotient map $f: X \to Y$: a (surjective) map such that $$\forall O: f^{-1}[O] \text{ open in } X \iff O \subseteq Y \text{open in } Y$$

And those maps preserve local connectedness, as I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2427174/4280).

Comment: Hi professor Brandsma, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671596/a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space-v-can-be-equipped-with-a-norm)?