# Any linear transformation between two finite dimensional topological vector spaces is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

**Theorem**

Any linear transformation $T$ from one finite dimensional topological vector space $V$ into another finite dimensional topological vector $W$
space is necessarily continuous.

Unfortunately I don't be able to prove the statement so could someone prove it? Then if the statement is generally false is it false if $V=\Bbb R^m$ and $W=\Bbb R^m$ too? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Do you require TVS to be $T_1$?

Comment: See Treves, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels. Probably it is proved there

Comment: @user10354138 Not necessarily.

Comment: Then you get silly examples like the identity map $(\mathbb{R},\text{indiscrete})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\text{usual})$.

Comment: @user10354138 Umm...unfortunately $\Bbb R$ equipped with indiscrete topology is not a topological vector space! Is this incorrect?

Comment: No!  Since you didn't require a TVS to be $T_1$ any vector space with the indiscrete topology is a TVS (since every map to an indiscrete space is automatically continuous, in particular $+\colon X\times X\to X$ and $\cdot\colon\mathbb{R}\times X\to X$ are continuous)

Comment: @user10354138 Okay, so if I suppose that the topological vector spaces must be $T_1$ then is the theorem true? and so how to prove it?

Comment: Any finite-dimensional $T_1$ TVS (therefore Hausdorff) must be [the standard $\mathbb{F}^n$ for some $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445547), and you know linear maps $\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^m$ are continuous ($\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @user10354138 How is $\Bbb F^n$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: See if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous) helps.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I read it. However I don't understand why  *a finite dimensional topological vector space can be equipped with a norm which gives the same topology*. Indeed sometimes ago I post an answer (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671596/a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space-v-can-be-equipped-with-a-norm?noredirect=1#comment7545198_3671596)) where I ask this but unfortunately nobody answered. So what can you say about?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Okay, take a look at Section $3.4$ of [this PDF](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~razk/iWeb/My_Site/Teaching_files/TVS.pdf). In Proposition $3.17$ take $\mathscr{X}$ itself to be $n$-dimensional and let $\mathscr{Y}=\mathscr{X}$. Any basis for $\mathscr{X}$ gives you an isomorphism from $\mathscr{F}^n$ to $\mathscr{X}$, and the theorem says that it’s a homeomorphism. Here $\mathscr{F}$ is the scalar field, and it’s pretty clear from what he says earlier in the PDF that he has $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ in mind. Thus, in effect you’re just looking at the normed space $\mathscr{F}^n$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $T:V\longmapsto W$ a linear transformation, and $\mathcal{B}=\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ a basis of V.
In finite dimension all norms are equivalents, let $||x||=\sum_{i=1}^n\vert x_i\vert$, then $$||f(x)||=||f(x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n)|| \leqslant |x_1|||f(e_1)||+...+|x_n||f(e_n)||$$
Let $M=\underset{i\in\{1,...,n\}}{sup}||f(e_i)||$, then $$  |x_1|||f(e_1)||+...+|x_n||f(e_n)|| \leqslant M(|x_1|+...+|x_n|)=M||x|| $$
$\implies $ $$||f(x)|| \leqslant  M||x||$$

Comment: Okay, and if $V$ and $W$ are not normed spaces?

Comment: Perhaps do you know the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671596/a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space-v-can-be-equipped-with-a-norm?noredirect=1#comment7545198_3671596) question?

Comment: You can see  <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous>

Comment: There is the same problem there too