# Is this “Combesque” Space path connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Pardon my English.

I have to prove that this space is or isn’t path connected:$$K=\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}\cup\bigl[(0,2)\times(0,2)\bigr]\setminus\left\{\left(\frac1n,y\right)\,\middle|\,y\in(0,1)\right\}.$$

We have figured out that it is connected, and kind of similar to a comb space.

How would one go about doing that?

Comment: What is $n$? Did you mean $(\frac{1}{y},y)$?

Comment: By finding, for any two points in $K$, an explicit path connecting them.

Comment: @freakish I'm pretty confident $n$ is intended to range over the positive integers.  But you're right that should be explicit in the problem statement.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for editing the post.

Comment: @freakish yes it was indeed n\in\mathbb{N} and thank you so much for your help. Your solution is even more detailed than expected!

Comment: Most of the editing was done by @JoseCarlosSantos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the last piece of your $K$ is actually $\{(1/n, y)\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}, y\in(0,1)\}$. In that case your $K$ is not path connected. So you have an example of a connected but not path connected space.

> **Lemma 1.** If $\lambda:[0,1]\to X$ is a path to a Hausdorff space then the image is [locally connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space).

*Proof.* Since $X$ is Hausdorff and $[0,1]$ is compact, then $\lambda$ is closed, in particular a quotient map onto its image. And [being locally connected is preserved under quotients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426794/a-quotient-of-a-locally-connected-space-is-locally-connected). $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** If $F\subseteq K$ is any subset such that $(0,0)\in F$ and $(0,0)$ is not isolated in $F$ then $F$ is not locally connected.

*Proof.* Consider the open ball $B$ around $(0,0)$ of radius $1$ (the radius is important so that we don't go above vertical lines). Now let $V\subseteq B\cap F$ be any open neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. Since $(0,0)$ is not isolated in $F$ then $V$ contains some point $v\neq (0,0)$. Write down $v=(x_v,y_v)$ and note that $x_v>0$ by our definition of $K$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $0<1/n<x_v$. Since $V$ is a subset of $B$ and $K$ then no point in $V$ can have the first coordinate equal to $1/n$. This implies that $V$ can be decomposed into two nonempty, open and disjoint subsets:

$$V^-=\{(x,y)\in V\ |\ x<1/n\}$$
$$V^+=\{(x,y)\in V\ |\ x>1/n\}$$
$$V=V^-\cup V^+$$

In particular $V$ is disconnected. By the arbitrary choice of $V$ we conclude that $F$ is not locally connected. $\Box$

> **Corollary.** $K$ is not path connected.

*Proof.* Assume $\lambda:[0,1]\to K$ is a path, $F=im(\lambda)$ and $(0,0)\in F$. Then by Lemma 1 our $F$ is locally connected. But then by Lemma 2 our $(0,0)$ point has to be isolated in $F$. In particular either $F$ is disconnected or $F=\{(0,0)\}$. The first case of course cannot happen because $F$ is an image of a connected space. Thus $F=\{(0,0)\}$ and so $\lambda$ is a constant path. In particular no point other than $(0,0)$ can be connected to $(0,0)$ inside $K$. $\Box$